# JQuery Div value returns Undefined

Tags: jquery

I have a div:

```
<div class="form_result">hello</div>


 var mb = $('.form_result').text();
 alert("Value of div is: " + mb.value);
```

The alert is returning Undefined.

Tried JQuery version 1.9.1 and 1.8.3 ...same result.

Comment: No need of doing `.value`.. `mb` is enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need `.value`

```
alert("Value of div is: " + mb)
```

---

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) get the text inside the div

---

`.value` is used for `form` elements like `input,select,radio,checkbox`

Answer (score 1):

`alert("Value of div is: " + mb);` do like this